# Python 3 str.format with decimal place

Tags: python

```py
def ShowData(data = (x)):
       for r in data: 
        print (“{:}, {:.2f}”.format(x, x))
```

keep getting this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-9963f96f39ca>", line 8
    print (“{:}, {:.2f}”.format(x, x))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: Please add the error message into the question, not as an image, since some users cannot access image hosting sites

Comment: “fancy quotes” got into your code somehow. Did you type it in an editor, or copy and paste it from somewhere? Either way, you need to change them to "straight quotes".

Comment: Change `“` for `"`.

Comment: Aside from the (correct) answer you already have, you will also need to indent `print` a bit so that it's not at the same indentation level as `for`. You can have multiple lines in the body of a for loop, and Python figures out which ones are included by looking for which are at a deeper indentation level. So it would look at your code and conclude there are zero lines in the for loop, which is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the **“** charachter with this **"** ?

```
# data is a list of lists
def ShowData(data = (x)):
       for r in data: 
        print ("{:}, {:.2f}".format(x, x))
```

Comment: but x isn't defined, how would you define x?

Comment: @AnnaWilson That is a separate, unrelated question.

Comment: You should try to tell us what you want to do in other question, so i can help @AnnaWilson

Comment: when I do what you suggested it gave me this error: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4284804758d7> in <module>
      3 # Defines a "ShowData" function for later usage
      4 # data is a list of lists
----> 5 def ShowData(data = (x)):
      6        for r in data:
      7         print ("{:}, {:.2f}".format(x, x))

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Can you open another question and tell us what do you expect from this function?@AnnaWilson

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman it won't let me, but I need it to print the data with 2 decimal places

Comment: try this ; 
def ShowData(data):
       for r in data: 
         print ("{0:.2f}".format(r))

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman gave me this error:  File "<ipython-input-17-079d9aa87622>", line 6
    for r in data:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AnnaWilson maybe indent error?

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman def ShowData(data = (x,x)):
       for r in data:
              print (“{:}, {:.2f}”.format(x, x))     error:  File "<ipython-input-28-271567fe3bcb>", line 8
    print (“{:}, {:.2f}”.format(x, x))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: data = (x,x) is not acceptable, use only data try what i sent in previous comment

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman when I use the option you gave me it messes up my code later, when I have to use the ShowData function